# Read CSV file and filter results

Tags: python, csv, parsing

Im writing a script where one of its functions is to read a CSV file that contain URLs on one of its rows. Unfortunately the system that create those CSVs doesn't put double-quotes on values inside the URL column so when the URL contain commas it breaks all my csv parsing.

This is the code I'm using:

```
with open(accesslog, 'r') as csvfile, open ('results.csv', 'w') as enhancedcsv: 
        reader = csv.DictReader(csvfile)
        for row in reader: 
            self.uri =  (row['URL'])
            self.OriCat = (row['Category'])
            self.query(self.uri)
            print self.URL+","+self.ServerIP+","+self.OriCat+","+self.NewCat"
```

This is a sample URL that is breaking up the parsing - this URL comes on the row named "URL". (note the commas at the end)

```
ams1-ib.adnxs.com/ww=1238&wh=705&ft=2&sv=43&tv=view5-1&ua=chrome&pl=mac&x=1468251839064740641,439999,v,mac,webkit_chrome,view5-1,0,,2,
```

The following row after the URL always come with a numeric value between parenthesis. Ex: (9999) so this could be used to define when the URL with commas end.

How can i deal with a situation like this using the csv module?

Comment: Is comma your column-delimiter?

Comment: Yes. commas are the column delimiter.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do it a little more manually. Try this

```
def process(lines, delimiter=','):
    header = None
    url_index_from_start = None
    url_index_from_end = None
    for line in lines:
        if not header:
            header = [l.strip() for l in line.split(delimiter)]
            url_index_from_start = header.index('URL')
            url_index_from_end = len(header)-url_index_from_start

        else:
            data = [l.strip() for l in line.split(delimiter)]

            url_from_start = url_index_from_start
            url_from_end = len(data)-url_index_from_end

            values = data[:url_from_start] + data[url_from_end+1:] + [delimiter.join(data[url_from_start:url_from_end+1])]
            keys = header[:url_index_from_start] + header[url_index_from_end+1:] + [header[url_index_from_start]]

            yield dict(zip(keys, values))
```

Usage:

```
lines = ['Header1, Header2, URL, Header3',
         'Content1, "Content2", abc,abc,,abc, Content3']

result = list(process(lines))

assert result[0]['Header1'] == 'Content1'
assert result[0]['Header2'] == '"Content2"'
assert result[0]['Header3'] == 'Content3'
assert result[0]['URL'] == 'abc,abc,,abc'

print(result)
```

Result:

```
>>> [{'URL': 'abc,abc,,abc', 'Header2': '"Content2"', 'Header3': 'Content3', 'Header1': 'Content1'}]
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you considered using Pandas to read your data in?

Another possible solution would be to use regular expressions to pre-process the data...

```
#make a list of everything you want to change
old = re.findall(regex, f.read())

#append quotes and create a new list
new = []
for url in old:
     url2 = "\""+url+"\""
     new.append(url2)

#combine the lists
old_new = list(zip(old,new))

#Then use the list to update the file:
f = open(filein,'r')
filedata = f.read()
f.close()
for old,new in old_new:    
    newdata = filedata.replace(old,new)    
f = open(filein,'w')
f.write(newdata)
f.close()
```

Comment: Would be more helpful if you included the actual regex used.